# Ruby on Rails and haml syntax error with text mate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, textmate

I am using haml in ruby on rails and editing it in text mate. Here is my code copied right out of text mate. I get real weird tabbing syntax error, this is the extracted source. Not sure how to resolve this.

```
1: %ul
2:   - @jobs.each do |job|
3:     %li
4:      = link_to(job) do
5:        %strong.job_title
6:          = job.title
7:        %span.description
```

**UPDATE**
I also get this error

```
Inconsistent indentation: "\t    " was used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.
```

Comment: You have stray tab in your HAML, probably at the beginning of your `link_to` line as that's where your indentation starts getting messed up.

Comment: line 4? looks like you have 1 space of indentation instead of 2. p.s. line 6 can be merged to line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this bundle
https://github.com/handcrafted/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle
then retype the code, should solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve this problem is to change **Tab Size** to *2* and check **Soft Tabs (Spaces)** - you can find this at the bottom of TextMate window.